# Django: reference static file from js in static file directory

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to call a static file from a js file placed in the static files directory of my Django project.
Here it is an example.
From my template I call a js from the static files in the following way:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
...
<script src="{% static 'js/init.js' %}"></script>
...
```

No problems till now.
So, I have a static file called **init.js** that has a function with this line of code:

```
global: { href: 'css/style.css', containers: '70em', grid: { gutters: ['2.5em', 0] } },
```

where **init.js** is a static file and **css/style.css** is a static file too.
Naturally changing the code in the following way is causing problems to the **init.js** file that is not able to recognize python/Django code

```
{% load staticfiles %}
global: { href: "{% static 'css/style.css' %}", containers: '70em', grid: { gutters: ['2.5em', 0] } },
```

Is there a way to call the static file directly from another static file like this case?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can save it somewhere in template

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">var tem_css_location = {% static 'css/style.css' %}</script>
```

and now you can call tem_css_location in init.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">var tem_css_location = {% static 'css/style.css' %}</script>
<script src="{% static 'js/init.js' %}"></script>
```

in  init.js will look like this:

```
global: { href: tem_css_location, containers: '70em', grid: { gutters: ['2.5em', 0] } },
```

Comment: Thank you mate, this is a very good answer!
especially putting the location into a variable and reusing it in the other js file instead of doing all in the template

Answer (score -1):

Let me suggest a different way of approaching the problem.  Consider fetching the static file location in the view, then render it to template.  If this fits your need, you can simplify your js and sidestep the issue entirely.

```
from django.templatetags.static import static

url = static('x.jpg')
```